# Problem passing dictionary to API via requests.post()

Tags: python, django, rest

As noted below, I am trying to pass the dictionary ***data*** to the API.

```
def create_flow_and_phases(request):

    data = {
        "name": "name_example",
        "description":"description_example",
        "category": 2,
        "precedents": [2,3],
        "users": [1],
        "phases": [{
                "name": "phase_name",
                "description": "description name",
                "sequence_number": 1,
                "precedents": [1]
            }]
    }

    # Making a POST request to save flow_and_phases
    url = API_HOST + "/api/flows/save_flow_and_phases/"

    answer = requests.post(url, data=data, headers={'Authorization': 'Token ' + request.session['user_token']})

    if not answer.ok:
        raise Exception("An error occurred while creating flow.")
```

Below, you can see that the dictionary ***data*** format is the same one passed in Insomnia to the API and that it works perfectly.

```
{
  "name": "Testando criação de fluxo pelo Insomnia",
  "description": "Fluxo teste simulando informações de trato e colheita de café na fazendo fictícia Quipo",
  "category": 2,
  "precedents": [2, 3],
    "users": [1],
    "phases": [
         {
            "name": "Trato anual",
            "description": "Descrição teste fase 1.",
            "sequence_number": 1,
            "precedents": []
         },
        {
            "name": "Trato anual 2",
            "description": "Descrição teste fase 2.",
            "sequence_number": 2,
            "precedents": [1]
         }
    ]
}
```

The backend receives ***data*** as below

```
flow_data = dict(data) # data is passed as parameter
```

But when I go to run the debub, the data referring to phases are not passed to the API as shown in the screenshot below

[image]

As shown in the image, the list with phases is not being passed. What's happening? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post the data as JSON, nested data does not work as regular POST data. You can pass the data in the `json` parameter and requests should handle the headers and serialisation for you

```
answer = requests.post(url, json=data, headers={'Authorization': 'Token ' + request.session['user_token']})
```